# CENM (Corda Enterprise Network Manager) 1.2 custom issuance workflow plugin

Tags: plugins, corda

I am trying to build a custom workflow plugin for CENM 1.2 identity manager issuance scenario.

I have referred to this link: https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.2/workflow.html for the same. The Git Hub links on this page are broken and I can not see the examples referred in the page.

I am trying to build Example 2, by creating a new class. How do I resolve the ENM Plugin API and other dependencies? Where are these Jars available for building a custom plugin?

Comment: Let me find the plugin jars link and send you.

Comment: @sneha Have you found the relevant links yet ?

Comment: That documentation implies you do not need anything else apart from the CENM binaries which should include that base plugin class. So you extend your class from this base class WorkflowPlugin<CertificateSigningRequest>. Let me know if you already tried that and ran into issues.That page also has a simple example for reference on how to create your own plugin.

Comment: Yes I tried to extend from WorkflowPlugin<CertificateSigningRequest>. The problem is WorkflowPlugin class itself could not be located, this class should be in the CENM API ... But not sure which JAR that corresponds to ... Unpacking CENM full of course lead to various service (e.g. Identity Manager etc.) related zips and Jars. The issue is still not resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including bundled.jar as a dependency resolved the issue.